# Different predicate in Prolog, don't work (always false)

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog for an university exam using SWI Prolog and I have some question about this simple program that implement the **different** predicate that say TRUE if two element are different (if they do not match) and say FALSE if they match.

This is the code:

```
different(X,X) :- !,
              fail.

diferent(_,_).
```

The problem is that if I try to execute the following query in the Prolog shell I always obtain FALSE:

```
[debug] 10 ?- different(a,b).
false.

[debug] 11 ?- different(a,a).
false.
```

As you can see the first query have to say TRUE because a don't match with b

Why?

Comment: Why debug when stackoverflow?

Comment: I apologize for my stupid question...I have spent all night at work at office and I was just a litle bit in mental confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change diferent(_,_) to different(_,_). Ie it is a spelling error. 
Your second predicate is not being examined as it does not match your query.

The program should be

```
different(X,X) :- !,fail.
different(_,_).
```

Comment: OMG...I just came back from a whole night at work in office...evidently are not yet able to concentrate ....I need more coffee...tnx

Answer (score 2):

This "exercise" is pointless. **Use [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)!**

IMO the **only** reasonable definition of `different/2` is:

```
different(A,B) :- dif(A,B).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emacs for editing your prolog files (If not I strongly recommend you switching to it) I suggest you using hi-lock-mode. I will highlight in a pattern-like fashion all matches in the file whenever the cursor is over a word. It can save you hours of pain when you develop bigger projects.

[image]